# MySQL query apparently returning extra row

Tags: php, mysql

While retrieving the data from MySQL through PHP, it retrieves one extra row which is NOT present in database. Why?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM info");

while($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    $image = $row['image_path'];
    $caption = $row['caption'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src=<?php echo $image;?>>
            <div class="caption text-center"><h3><?php echo $caption;?></h3></div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="modal(<?php  echo $id;?>)">View</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Column END -->
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: To paraphrase Strawberry, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Use your html code inside while loop, and you are returning one record or multiple records?@OmkarPathak

Comment: Returning multiple, but last record(a blank record)get added up @parthmahida

Comment: Try running query in phpmyadmin to confirm that there isnt any extra record.@OmkarPathak

Comment: I have confirmed, phpmyadmin doesnt return any extra record!

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are using

`$row = $sql->fetch_array()`;

which defaults to

`$row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);`

and returns a NULL value at the end of the result set because of the `MYSQLI_ROW` parameter which is included in `MYSQLI_BOTH`

You can do this to fix it:

`while ($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: np   source was  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
  for anyone wondering